# Do synchronous calls (e.g. tcp::socket.send) trigger pending async operations?

Tags: asynchronous, boost-asio

Quick question:

Say I start an `async_receive()` on a `boost::asio::tcp::socket`, and then a bit later, I start a blocking (synchronous) write using `socket.send(stuff)`.

Will this trigger any pending `async_receive()`, or must I manually call the `run()` function in the `io_context`?

Answer (score 0):

For any async operations you need to start the main loop, meaning `run()`. Be advised, though, if there is no work, it will return immediately.

You can, however, do anything else while the asio poll reactor waits for en event to arrive.

So, `async_receive` will trip **if** a read operation is available regardless of whether you have written to the socket synchronously or asynchronously.

In other words, if you write to the socket synchronously and something else responds back, your `async_receive` handler will get called. A write on its own will not.